# forward response to frontend MongoDB React

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

i am not able to forward the response from the backend to the frontend.
i already define the request to check if a user exist based on his mail and password

this is how the server.js file look like

```
const router = express.Router();

// This section will help you get a list of all the records.
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  let collection = await db.collection("records");
  let results = await collection.find({}).toArray();
  res.send(results).status(207);
  
});

// This section will help you get a single record by id
router.get("/:email&:password", async (req, res) => {
  let collection = await db.collection("records");
 
  let query = { $and: [ {email: req.params.email} ,{password: req.params.password}] };
  
  let result = await collection.findOne(query);
  
  if (!result) {
    
    res.status(400).send('user not found')
    }
  else {
   
    res.status(200).send('user found')
  }
});
```

the frontend function that is supposed to catch the reponse is defined like this:
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

```
async function onSubmit(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   const editedPerson = {
    email: form.email,
    password: form.password,

   };

   
   const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5050/login/${email.email}&${password.password}`);
   

  // console.log(response.status);

if(response.status == 200) {
  const record = await response.json();
  alert("user found");
  
  console.log(record);
  
}
else {
  alert("not found")
};
```

```
                                                      -
```

Comment: The '&' in '/:email&:password' should be a '/' if you want to use req.params.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways for you too pass data via the url right now your in the middle of the 2

1. part of the route

> /login/someName/somePassword

to do it this way on the backend you just need to change

```
router.get("/login/:email/:password", async (req, res) => {});
```

and on the fronend change the url

```
const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5050/login/${email.email}/${password.password}`);
```

2. As a query string

> /login?email=someEmail&password=somePassword

to do it this way update the url in the backend

```
router.get("/login", async (req, res) => {
    const {email, password } = req.query;
    //rest of code... 
});
```

and on the frontend

```
const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5050/login?email=${email.email}&password=${password.password}`);
```

Comment: Hi, thx a lot for your support, i am one more step near my target :)

Comment: Np, is it still not working?